# Как создать линк на /var/www и дать права на запись пользователю?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, bash, apache2

На Ubuntu установлен Apache с папкой для документов /var/www

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 окт.  21 23:15 www
```

Как видно писать в нее может только root. Мне было бы удобно создать символическую ссылку у себя в домашней папке ~/www и дать своему пользователю права на запись в эту папку. Как это сделать на bash-e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# ln -s /var/www/username /home/username/dirname # chown -c username /home/username/dirname
```

Answer (score 3):

Можешь заюзать [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_userdir.html) и не городить костыли

Comment: ну мод юзер дир тоже клево, а это вот прям костыли?

Comment: Во-первых, есть общепринятый метод для решения проблемы.Во-вторых, мне бы не подошел ваш метод:`byshovets@byshovets-X61:~$ sudo mkdir -p tmp/test/dirbyshovets@byshovets-X61:~$ sudo ln -s tmp/test .byshovets@byshovets-X61:~$ sudo chown -c byshovets testизменён владелец «test» с root на byshovetsbyshovets@byshovets-X61:~$ touch test/dir/filetouch: невозможно выполнить touch для «test/dir/file»: Отказано в доступе`